# Gradle sync failure while using ndk. Android Studio Build points to External native build issues

Tags: android, android-studio, cmake, android-ndk

Build window[image: Build window]

Event Log Window[image: Event Log Window]

terminal Window[image: terminal Window]

Hello SO. I am quite new to using ndk for android development. When I create a new project, android studio finds it difficult to sync the project and I have the following errors as shown in the attached images. I have tried to go through similar solutions from similar problems here on SO but came out unsuccessful. Can any one help me?

Comment: What version of the gradle plugin are you using?

Comment: Please include the **text of the logcat** (**not** images) so we can search on errors we find. Also your build.gradle files (root and app level).

Comment: @Jon Goodwin. I actually solved the problem. In the project directory under build.gradle, I modified  classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3' to  classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1' and the problem was solved.

Comment: @Dan Albert. Your question prompted me to tweak the classpath dependency under build.gradle and I solved my problem